# How to configure JBPM's REST API to return date-time in JSON as value instead of a JSON object with "java.util.Date" property?

Tags: jbpm, kie

This issue is more specific to Process Server (or KIE Server before JBPM/RHPAM 7).

The Swagger document of the Process Server (`http://${host}:${port}/kie-server/docs`) shows that many JSON dates are `string($date-time)`.

However, the JSON payload returned has the following format:

```
"timestamp": {
    "java.util.Date": 1540584717937
}
```

In fact, [jBPM's documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.36.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#kie-server-extensions-con_kie-apis) in many REST response examples also show dates in that form above.

Is there some configuration that will allow the serialization of dates into other formats of dates as a value (string, ISO 8601, etc.) instead of this odd JSON object in which a JSON field called "java.util.Date" is set to the milliseconds value of Java's `java.util.Date` object?

*"Be conservative (strict) in what you do, be liberal (lenient) in what you accept from others,"* states the Robustness Principle. But the way that a date is serialized from jBPM is causing unnecessary trouble for [non-Java] consumers to parse the date value. Some amount of post-processing is necessary on the client side unless this can be resoled on the server side.

Any help or insight into how this configuration can be achieved is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To get date in a readable format  like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", you have to  add @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") annotation to the field in pojo class, like as

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
. .  .. 
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
private Date effectiveDate;
```

Comment: This question's context is with respect to jBPM. These POJOs are already compiled and packaged in their JAR files. Are you familiar with jBPM?

Comment: you need to modify and recompile POJO classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the System Environment Variables for the [JSON Marshaller](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-server-parent/kie-server-api/src/main/java/org/kie/server/api/marshalling/json/JSONMarshaller.java#L102).

```
org.kie.server.json.format.date="true"
org.kie.server.json.date_format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```